# How to convert a map to escaped string in json form in kotlin?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, objectmapper

I have a mutableMap,

```
val invoiceAdditionalAttribute = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("clinetId",12345)
invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("clientName", "digital")
invoiceAdditionalAttribute.put("payload", "xyz")
```

I want to convert it into string which looks like escaped json

the output should be,

```
"{\"clinetId\":\"12345\", \"clientName\":\"digital\", \"payload\":\"xyz\"}"
```

Currently, I am using Gson library,

```
val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)
```

and the output is

```
{"clinetId":12345,"clientName":"digital","payload":"xyz"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` extension function on `String` class:

```
val invoiceAdditionalAttribute = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["clinetId"] = 12345.toString()
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["clientName"] = "digital"
invoiceAdditionalAttribute["payload"] = "xyz"

val json = gson.toJson(invoiceAdditionalAttribute)
        .replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

`json` now contains string:

```
{\"clinetId\":\"12345\",\"clientName\":\"digital\",\"payload\":\"xyz\"}
```